# using IIf in a gridview control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to change the image url of an image control based on condition inside gridview below is my markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
            ImageUrl='<%# IIf(CDate(Eval("startdate")) < CDate(Eval("expdate")),"~/iWebmallManager/Images/bullet_red.png",
                "~/iWebmallManager/Images/bullet_green.png" %>'
        /> 
    </ItemTemplate>                                                  
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The IIf statement didn't work. i dont know what I am doing right please help

Comment: Its been resolved thanks -  I omitted the last close bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do that in [codebehind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx), since it increases the readability and is easier to debug:

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim rowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem,DataRowView)
        Dim Image1 = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("Image1"),Image)
        Dim startdate = DirectCast(rowView("startdate"), Date)
        Dim expdate = DirectCast(rowView("expdate"), Date)
        If startDate < expdate
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/iWebmallManager/Images/bullet_red.png"
        Else
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/iWebmallManager/Images/bullet_green.png"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim I have figure out my mistake it was the closing bracket of the IIf statement.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to use IIF anymore since the ternary operator found its way into VB.NET with `IF`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/03/11/if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim.aspx The second portion of the statement will not be exexuted if the first one is already true(faster and safer).